# different alignment on some lines of an align* envirnoment

Tags: align

I would like to typeset a set of equations, where a bunch of them a short (fit on one line) and one of them is long.

I would like it to look something like the output of the following:

```
\begin{align*}
   && a&=b & c&=d & e&=f & g&=h &&
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
  x < (a^2+b^2)\cos( (a+b)/(c+d) ) \sqrt{g^2+1} < 3
\end{align*}
```

I would like the equations on the first line evenly spaced out and centered, and the equation on the second line centered with them overall.

Two problems with the above:
1) Vertical space between the two align's.  Easily fixed with `\vspace{-1em}`.
2) Being separate align's, they may break across pages, which I do not want.

I can of course do this with one align and a bunch of `\qquad` instead of a bunch of `&`, but using the `&` makes the overall spacing and centering nicer.
I have tried putting the first equation inside an aligned but the two equations are not centered with each other.

Answer (score 1):

May be like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{gather*}
    a=b \qquad\quad c=d \qquad\quad e=f \qquad\quad g=h  \\
  x < (a^2+b^2)\cos( (a+b)/(c+d) ) \sqrt{g^2+1} < 3
  \end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For evenly spaced equations, that don't need alignment, you don't need `align*`.

Comment: Maybe I should have added that the number of equations per line varies... meaning I'd have to work out the correct number of \quad and \qquad separately, and adjust if I add/remove an equation.  But this certainly does work.